# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to turn a string into a list of separate words--nothing but letters. However, as far as I can tell, unicode is causing the problems.

```
essay_text = ['This,', 'this,', 'this', 'and', 'that.']

def create_keywords(self):
    low_text = self.essay_text.lower()
    word_list = low_text.split()
    abcs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    for n in word_list:
        for m in n:
            for l in abcs:
                if m!=l:
                    n.remove(m)
        self.keywords.setdefault(n, 0)
        self.keywords[n] = word_list.count(n)
        for m in bad_words:
            if n==m:
                del self.keywords[n]
    print self.keywords
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

How can I solve this?

Update:
I don't understand why my strings are in unicode. If it is relevant, here is the class that this model lies under:

```
class Essay(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    essay_text = models.TextField()
    sources = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.title
```

Why are my strings in in unicode?

Comment: Just a tip - Your current code keeps redefining `abcs`.  It would be best to move that out of the loops so that it is only defined once.  Or, even better, use `ascii_lowercase` from the `string` module.

Comment: Do you have a `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in your code?  that would cause Python 2 to treat `'string'` as Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in your code?  That would cause Python 2.X to treat `'string'` as Unicode.

As others have said, strings aren't mutable and do not have a `remove` method.

There are a couple of modules that greatly simplify your goal:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

bad_words = ['and']

def create_keywords():
    essay_text = 'This, this, this and that.'
    # This regular expression finds consecutive strings of lowercase letters.
    # Counter counts each unique string and collects them in a dictionary.
    result = Counter(re.findall(r'[a-z]+',essay_text.lower()))
    for w in bad_words:
        result.pop(w)
    return dict(result) # return a plain dict instead of a Counter object.
```

Output:

```
>>> create_keywords()
{'this': 3, 'that': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is explicit: the `n` variable, which is a string, doesn't have a `remove` method - that's because strings are immutable in Python. You'll have to create a new string without the characters you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, meaning they cannot be changed. What you'll really need to do is create a new string in its place with just the letters:

```
def just_letters(s):
    return ''.join(l for l in s if l in string.lowercase)

word_list = [just_letters(word) for word in word_list]
```